# Any way to make liquibase use backtick instead of double quotation to quote keywords when creating schema?

Tags: hibernate, liquibase

I have a Springboot project with liquibase integrated. There is a table named order which is reserved keyword.
On startup, liquibase double quote the table name "order" and could create the schema without any error.
But later any sql statement uses the table would throw error saying cannot find table named order.
The sql generated use backtick `, which is right above the TAB key on keyboard.
is there anyway to make liquibase use backtick to quote keyword when creating schema?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with backtick or double quote. The issue is probably the case sensitivity. As soon as you use backticks or double quotes, the string within is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Liquibase do not have the policy of using backtick to quote keyword when creating a schema.